# Canvas dimensions are off

Tags: javascript, html, object, html5-canvas

I read that using multiple canvases instead of drawing everything to one is more efficient so while attempting this I noticed that I was writing code in double.  So I got the idea to make a function which would contain all the common variables.  Here's the code:

```
function CanvasElement(id, width, height, parent){
     this.id = id;
     this.width = width;
     this.height = height;
     this.parent = parent;
     this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

     document.getElementById(parent).appendChild(this.canvas);
}
```

However when I use this function like so:

```
/*Parameters: id, width, height, parent element*/
var canvasBg = new CanvasElement('canvasBg', 640, 480, 'animation');
```

This is the problem: the final canvas element is smaller than its supposed to be.  If one is to make the canvas outside the function "normally" then the final canvas would be 640x480px.  However when using the  function to create the element the dimensions are considerably smaller.

Any ideas on why this is happening or how to remedy it?

I don't want to rewrite those lines to create multiple canvases.  I'd rather have an object I can create and just give the attributes in parameters.  I would also like to know if I'm even on the right track on how to implement something like this.  Suggestions on how to improve or if necessary apply different methods to achieve the same results are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are not actually doing anything with the `id`/`width`/`height` values. It would be easier to see exactly what's going wrong if you showed the old version of the code.

Comment: FWIW Take a while to go through your code and try to understand what's going on before posting a question. Use Javascript Inspector or Firebug or similar tools. This will help you develop a better understanding of how stuff works and what doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't appear to actually be assigning the width or height to the canvas itself, just the `CanvasElement` object you have wrapping it.

Try this instead:

```
function CanvasElement(id,width,height,parent) {
    this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    this.canvas.id = id;
    this.canvas.width = width;
    this.canvas.height = height;
    document.getElementById(parent).appendChild(this.canvas);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, will need to test, but shouldn't it be `this.canvas.style.width = width + 'px';` and so on with the height. Or does it work ok like this?

Comment: @Mutahhir: that's the same as the difference between `<canvas width="640"` and `<canvas style="width: 640px;"`. Those are not identical.

Comment: @DCoder Right, thought so, but these things still confuse me. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: Actually it is different. `this.canvas.width` will set the view of the canvas, whereas `this.canvas.style.width` will set the port of the canvas. So you could set the width to 200 and the style.width to 400 and result in a scaled canvas.